# WebPage inaccessible replace errors

Tags: php

I have a weird problem when i have an error in my php code my webpage just display webpage inaccessible but not the errors. I have change my php init file by:

```
error_reporting  =  E_ALL & E_NOTICE & E_STRICT
```

but it don't change anything

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: oula look like my question is not really good >< sry my problem is that usually when i have error in my code i have something like error 87854 at line 145 but actualy i have a white page with only webpage inaccessible.

Comment: Is "display_errors" set to on? Do you have a custom error handler?

Comment: "display_errors" is on and i don't use custom error handler.
I use wampserver 2.2 and PHP 5.2.7 if it can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong operator here. Your line will only dispalay errors of type E_ALL and E_NOTICE and E_STRICT. Since an error can not match all three types, none is shown.

Use the or operator `|` to include something or the and-not operatr `~&' to exclude something from E_ALL.

```
error_reporting (E_ALL | E_NOTICE | E_STRICT);
```

If you are talking about the settings in your php.ini, use this documentation:

```
; Common Values:
;   E_ALL (Show all errors, warnings and notices including coding     standards.)
;   E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE  (Show all errors, except for notices)
;   E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT  (Show all errors, except for notices and coding standards warnings.)
;   E_COMPILE_ERROR|E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR|E_ERROR|E_CORE_ERROR  (Show only errors)
; Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED
; Development Value: E_ALL
; Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
; http://php.net/error-reporting
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

**Warning**: If you are specifying your error levels somewhere else, ex an apache config, use the numbers behind those constants and NOT the constants!

http://php.net/manual/de/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting

Comment: Thank you it's work now and sry if some people already ask the same question i don't find it.